# Dynamic int value

Tags: android, dynamic, integer

int[] numbers = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

**12** rows in my ListView,

I want the first item to have the lowest index in the array and the last item to have the highest index of the array.

The reason is because there is going to be a fade between the first item and the last and I want it to be with these 5 colors no matter how many list items I have.

But what happens when,

if items = 12,

1 has number 1,

2 has number 1,

3 has number 2,

4 has number 2

etc...

What if I have more numbers or more items? Am I completely stupid? Yelp!

Edit:

First item: 0%,

Last item: 100%,

No matter how many items!

Comment: why dont you assign the value inside getview() of your listadapter if you have made a custom adapter then its very easy

Comment: Wow you're fast!! How do you mean? Think of it like this,
1st item -> 0%, 
last item -> 100% no matter how many items.

Comment: in your getview() method you have a position variable that correspond to the array you are using so try switch(position%5) { case 0:int color = numbers[0] break; similarly for others}

Comment: @IllegalArgument That wouldn't work. It would just end up looping the colors. 0%5 = 0, 1%5 = 1,...., 5%5 = 0

Comment: item.setColorFilter( Color.parseColor( allColors[ ( position / itemCount ) ] ), Mode.SRC_ATOP); did not do the trick.

Comment: why dont sort your array?

Comment: @tana - what would that accomplish here?

Comment: listview has adapter, adapter base on your array. sorting array will automatically solve your problem.

Comment: Not sure how to do that @Tana. 
Feels like this is a simple math problem..

Answer (score 2):

I noticed this from your comments: `item.setColorFilter( Color.parseColor( allColors[ ( position / itemCount ) ] ), Mode.SRC_ATOP);`

You are using `position / itemCount`. I assume that both of those are integers, which means that since position is smaller than itemCount, this division will always return 0. What you want to do is to find a relative position for an item in your item list. This position can then be used to find a corresponding position in the number list.

```
double pos = (double)position/(double)itemCount; // item 5 has 5/12 = 0.42
int colorPos = pos*allColors.length(); // Find position based on number of colors
// item 5: 0.42*5 = 2.1, cast to int ->2. 5 gets color at index 2

item.setColorFilter( Color.parseColor( allColors[ (colorPos) ] ), Mode.SRC_ATOP);
```

Hope this helps!